# Right Join not showing entries with "incomplete" data

Tags: mysql, sql, html-table, left-join, right-join

I'm trying to show a table with information gathered from 4 different tables.

| orden_trabajo_pk | concepto | descripcion | importe | ing_responsable_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 159460 | concept example1 | description | 18000 | 1 |
| 159461 | concept example2 | description | 8000 | 1 |

| cotizacion_pk | concepto | descripcion | importe | orden_trabajo_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010633 | concept example1 | description | 20000 | 159460 |

| factura_cliente_pk | fecha | importe | orden_trabajo_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A812 | 2022-10-15 | 19000 | 159460 |

| ing_responsable_pk | nombre | tel | planta_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Newdary | 123 | 1 |

I'm using 2 Right joins and 1 left join in the next way:

```
SELECT orden_trabajo.orden_trabajo_pk, orden_trabajo.concepto, orden_trabajo.importe, cotizacion.cotizacion_pk, cotizacion.importe, factura_cliente.factura_cliente_pk,factura_cliente.importe, ing_responsable.nombre, ing_responsable.telefono, factura_cliente.fecha
    FROM orden_trabajo 
    RIGHT JOIN cotizacion
    ON cotizacion.orden_trabajo_id = orden_trabajo.orden_trabajo_pk
    RIGHT JOIN factura_cliente
    ON factura_cliente.orden_trabajo_id = orden_trabajo.orden_trabajo_pk
    LEFT JOIN ing_responsable
    ON orden_trabajo.ing_responsable_id = ing_responsable.ing_responsable_pk
```

And it shows the table i'm trying to look at, however i'd like that it creates another row with the second "orden_trabajo_pk" (159461) with the next cells empty

Here's an example of the table I get:

| rowh1 | rowh2 | rowh3 | rowh4 | rowh5 | rowh6 | rowh7 | rowh8 | rowh9 | rowh10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5 | data6 | data7 | data8 | data9 | data10 |

And this is the table i want

| rowh1 | rowh2 | rowh3 | rowh4 | rowh5 | rowh6 | rowh7 | rowh8 | rowh9 | rowh10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5 | data6 | data7 | data8 | data9 | data10 |
| data1.1 | data2.1 | data3.1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Is there a way around it so it shows "incomplete" rows?

Comment: If you want all rows from `orden_trabajo` regardless of if they are in any other table this should be your starting point. Since you've used two right joins `factura_cliente` is actually your starting point, and since this only contains one order (159460) your end result will only have one order and the order 159461 will not be returned. If you change both right joins to left joins you should get the result you want.

Comment: As an aside, in over 15 years of writing SQL I can honestly say I have never used a right join in production code. I have used them very quickly when inspecting data to quickly swap tables in a simple query, but never in production. I also know of very few people who ever use them in production code either, the main reason is because they make queries much harder to read and cause issues exactly like this. My advice would be to stick with `LEFT` and `INNER` joins, and forget `RIGHT` joins exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the right joins, the query you are using is semantically equivalent to this:

```
SELECT  orden_trabajo_pk,
        orden_trabajo.concepto,
        orden_trabajo.importe,
        cotizacion_pk,
        cotizacion.importe,
        factura_cliente_pk,
        factura_cliente.importe,
        nombre,
        ing_responsable.telefono,
        fecha
FROM    factura_cliente
        LEFT JOIN orden_trabajo
            ON factura_cliente.orden_trabajo_id = orden_trabajo_pk
        LEFT JOIN cotizacion
            ON cotizacion.orden_trabajo_id = orden_trabajo_pk
        LEFT JOIN ing_responsable
            ON ing_responsable_id = ing_responsable_pk;
```

So you are starting with the records from `factura_cliente` which only contains one of the values for `orden_trabajo_id` (159460) the other record from `orden_trabajo` will not be returned.

You can get the result you need simply by changing your right joins to left joins:

```
SELECT  orden_trabajo_pk,
        orden_trabajo.concepto,
        orden_trabajo.importe,
        cotizacion_pk,
        cotizacion.importe,
        factura_cliente_pk,
        factura_cliente.importe,
        nombre,
        ing_responsable.telefono,
        fecha
FROM    orden_trabajo
        LEFT JOIN cotizacion
            ON cotizacion.orden_trabajo_id = orden_trabajo_pk
        LEFT JOIN factura_cliente
            ON factura_cliente.orden_trabajo_id = orden_trabajo_pk
        LEFT JOIN ing_responsable
            ON ing_responsable_id = ing_responsable_pk;
```

**[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lgil84-V)**

As noted in a comment, my honest advice would be to steer clear of `RIGHT JOIN`s. They are the cause of this issue for you, and ultimately any time you use a `RIGHT JOIN` the query can be written more logically (at least in my opinion) by changing the order of the tables and using `LEFT JOIN`.

As a final aside, I'd also recommend using aliases, this can be somewhat subjective, but I think most people would agree that it makes your queries faster to type, and easier to read, e.g.

```
SELECT  o.orden_trabajo_pk,
        o.concepto,
        o.importe,
        c.cotizacion_pk,
        c.importe,
        f.factura_cliente_pk,
        f.importe,
        i.nombre,
        i.telefono,
        f.fecha
FROM    orden_trabajo AS o
        LEFT JOIN cotizacion AS c
            ON c.orden_trabajo_id = o.orden_trabajo_pk
        LEFT JOIN factura_cliente AS f
            ON f.orden_trabajo_id = o.orden_trabajo_pk
        LEFT JOIN ing_responsable AS i
            ON i.ing_responsable_pk = o.ing_responsable_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this should work for you as a solution of your desired output.

```
SELECT
    ot.orden_trabajo_pk,
    ot.concepto,
    ot.importe,
    c.cotizacion_pk,
    c.importe,
    fc.factura_cliente_pk,
    fc.importe,
    ir.nombre,
    ir.tel,
    fc.fecha
From orden_trabajo ot
LEFT JOIN cotizacion c
    ON ot.orden_trabajo_pk = c.orden_trabajo_id
LEFT JOIN factura_cliente fc
    ON ot.orden_trabajo_pk = fc.orden_trabajo_id
LEFT JOIN ing_responsable ir
    ON ot.ing_responsable_id = ir.ing_responsable_pk
ORDER BY ot.orden_trabajo_pk ASC
```

Comment: Sadly it didn't work, i'm still obtaining the first table. Thanks for your input